# Spring boot MVC - HTML files work but JSP does not?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, model-view-controller

I've been trying to use JSP as a view for something im working on, but for some reason I keep getting whitelabel errors when using jsp files. I'm using a plain jsp file with some text to see if it works, no specific mapping or anything

If i use html files and "spring.mvc.view.suffix=.html" to the properties file then it works. But for some reason jsp files dont work.

I want to use jsp so I can make use of jstl tags to use for forms , I'm not sure how to do it with html files.

I have my view files under the static folder.

Only thing in my properties file is db source

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.springboot.application</groupId>
    <artifactId>safespot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>safespot</name>
    <description>Chat application</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        
        
           <!-- JSTL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- To compile JSP files -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Controller

```
@Controller
public class DemoController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String welcome() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

index.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>


</head>
<body>
    Hello World
</body>
</html>
```

[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSbN7.png)

Comment: post some of your project code, e.g. `pom.xml` and some sample code would be useful in order to help you.

Comment: I added the code, not sure where i'm going wrong :/

Comment: is it necessary to have your jsps in a `static` folder inside resources? I think spring boot uses the `resources/static` folder to serve static content. Why dont you try moving your jsps to a more classic path e.g. `webapp/WEB-INF/view` folder (which doesn't exist in your project structure, you can create it however) and see if it works? Make sure to change the `spring.mvc.view.prefix` properties accordingly e.g. `spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/view/`

Answer (score 0):

1. If you start your spring boot application as standalone application but do not deploy the war in an existing tomcat, then the `tomcat-embed-jasper` dependency must **NOT** have scope `provided` but `compile` (or maybe `runtime`), the same like `jstl`  *(btw, scope `compile` is the default, so you can omit it)*.
2. set `prefix` and `postfix`

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/classes/static/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
```

Comment: I've tried changing it, still getting this ```Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Sun Aug 22 18:29:53 CAT 2021
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available```

Comment: I am still writing ;-)

Comment: @ServletException: done - I hope my answer helps you

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've tried everything but it still seems to not render the jsp page, but will render the html

Comment: @ServletException Can you try to set you logging to a more fine grained detail and see if any hint gets printed there? In your `application.properties` add `logging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG`